# How do I add a cookie onclick of a button in Drupal7?

Tags: javascript, cookies, drupal-7

I have an article (Full Html) and I have a button. I want, when the button is clicked, to create a cookie and remember that the button is clicked. This is the code I currently have:

```
<button id="test" value="test" onclick="Press()">Press</button>

<script>

function Press() { text
}
</script>
```

How should I create the press function? This is the HTML of the article

Answer (score 0):

```
function Press() { 
     document.cookie="button=pressed";
}
```

`document.cookie` will create a cookie..